# Read from array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/shopify.php';
//require_once 'csv.php';
$t="bac2486aa2b31aa5aed1fdd62e77a4ae";
$sc = new ShopifyClient("mine-329.myshopify.com/", $t, API_KEY, SECRET);

if(!isset($t))
{
if(!isset($_GET['signature']))
{
    $url = $sc->getAuthorizeUrl("read_orders");
    header('Location: '.$url);
}
if(isset($_GET['code']))
{
    $accTok = $sc->getAccessToken($_GET['code']);
    echo "token=".$accTok;exit;
    $orders = $sc->call('GET', 'admin/orders.json', array('published_status'=>'published'));
    foreach($orders as $order) {
    echo $order['id'];
        echo $order['email'];
}
}
}
if(isset($t))
{
    $orders = $sc->call('GET', 'admin/orders.json', array('published_status'=>'published'));
    print_r($orders);
}
?>
```

Here is my output:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [order_number] => 1005
            [discount_codes] => Array
                (
                )

```
        [note_attributes] => Array
            (
            )
        [tax_lines] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [price] => 175.00
                        [rate] => 0.125
                        [title] => VAT
                  ) )

        [tags] => 
        [line_items] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [title] => Carnation mini - Alibi
                        [variant_id] => 700039407
                        [variant_title] => 
                        [vendor] => mine
                        [name] => Carnation mini - Alibi
                        [variant_inventory_management] => shopify
                        [properties] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [product_exists] => 1
                        [fulfillable_quantity] => 0
                        [tax_lines] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [price] => 75.00
                                        [rate] => 0.125
                                        [title] => VAT
                                    ) ))

                           [1] => Array
                    (

                        [title] => Calla lily white
                        [variant_id] => 700039091
                        [variant_title] => 
                        [vendor] => mine
                        [name] => Calla lily white
                        [variant_inventory_management] => shopify
                        [properties] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [product_exists] => 1
                        [fulfillable_quantity] => 0
                        [tax_lines] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [price] => 100.00
                                        [rate] => 0.125
                                        [title] => VAT
                                    ) ) ) )

        [shipping_lines] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [code] => Standard Shipping
                        [price] => 8.00
                        [source] => shopify
                        [title] => Standard Shipping
                        [tax_lines] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [price] => 0.00
                                        [rate] => 0.125
                                        [title] => VAT
                                    ) ) ) )

        [payment_details] => Array
            (
                [avs_result_code] => 
                [credit_card_bin] => 1
                [cvv_result_code] => 
                [credit_card_number] => â€¢â€¢â€¢â€¢ â€¢â€¢â€¢â€¢ â€¢â€¢â€¢â€¢ 1
                [credit_card_company] => Bogus
            )

        [billing_address] => Array
            (
                [address1] => 4th
                [address2] => 
                [city] => c
                [company] => 
                [country] => India
                [first_name] => selvarani
                [last_name] => raja
                [latitude] => 21.504394
                [longitude] => 82.71767
                [phone] => 919566552885
                [province] => Tamil Nadu
                [zip] => 6000014
                [name] => selvarani raja
                [country_code] => IN
                [province_code] => TN
            )

        [shipping_address] => Array
            (

                [country_code] => IN
                [province_code] => TN
            )

        [fulfillments] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (

                        [tracking_numbers] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [tracking_url] => 
                        [tracking_urls] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [receipt] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [line_items] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (

                                        [title] => Carnation mini - Alibi
                                        [variant_id] => 700039407
                                        [variant_title] => 
                                        [vendor] => mine
                                        [name] => Carnation mini - Alibi
                                        [variant_inventory_management] => shopify
                                        [properties] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                        [product_exists] => 1
                                        [fulfillable_quantity] => 0
                                        [tax_lines] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [price] => 75.00
                                                        [rate] => 0.125
                                                        [title] => VAT
                                                    ) ) )


                                [1] => Array
                                    (


                                        [variant_id] => 700039091


                                        [name] => Calla lily white
                                        [variant_inventory_management] => shopify
                                        [properties] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                        [product_exists] => 1
                                        [fulfillable_quantity] => 0
                                        [tax_lines] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [price] => 100.00
                                                        [rate] => 0.125
                                                        [title] => VAT
                                                    ) ) ) ) ) )
```

[refunds] => Array
                (
                )

```
        [customer] => Array
            (

                [last_order_name] => 
                [default_address] => Array
                    (

                        [province_code] => TN
                        [country_code] => IN
                        [default] => 1
                    ) ) ) )
```

Now I want to get product name, that is, Carnation mini - Alibi and Calla lily white.

If I put:

```
foreach($orders as order) { 

echo $order['line_items'][0]['name'];
```

It will display parse error. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Because of the missing semicolon on your `echo` line?

Comment: *cough*semicolon*cough*

Comment: Not to mention closing parenthesis if that indeed is his complete code

Comment: and the dollar sign in front of order. `order` should be `$order`

Comment: if you show us the parse error, we can exactly point to the error and fix

Comment: @Amal Murali: Thanks for edit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, trying again, lets make it easy to read:

```
$orders2 = $orders[0]['line_items'];
$i = 0;
foreach($orders2 as $order) { 
    echo $order[$i]['name'];
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: you can use foreach loop inside first foreach too rather than increment another variable

Comment: @Janaka R Rajapaksha: Can you explain in example code? Thanks!:)

Comment: @saina see my answer above

Comment: @Janaka R Rajapaksha: It will display lots of error like Invalid argument supplied for foreach() .. Thank you!.

Comment: @Janaka R Rajapaksha: I think your method is correct, but i don't know how to fix it. Can you help me? Thanks!.

Comment: @saina That is array sequence is wrong. sort out your array and get how many arrays inside of first array when achieving your item. then add number of foreach equaling that number or clearly mention your fully output array so that i will do it for you

Comment: @Janaka R Rajapaksha:Thanks:)

Comment: @Michael Smith: Thanks for response, now i got the error, Undefined offset: 0 and Undefined offset: 1.

Comment: @Michael Smith: I got answer.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

notice your fully outputted array `$orders`
then find how many arrays you should pass when achieving your targeted element
then add number of foreach loops according to that sequence and equaling that number of passed arrays.

Below is an example:
Assume you have:

```
`$orders = array( [0] => array( [0] => array( ['name'] = "some value for name" ) ) )`
```

Hint: number of parentheses are equal to number of arrays and then number of foreach loops.

```
foreach($orders as $order) { 

  foreach($order as $items){
    foreach($items as $item){
      echo $item['name'];
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should at least be:

```
foreach($orders as $order) { 
    echo $order['line_items'][0]['name'];
}
```

(Notice the dollar sign at the foreach construct.)

Comment: semicolon still missing at echo line

Comment: @JanakaRRajapaksha I've added the semicolon. Was originally pointing out the dollarsign was missing.